# Change shell on Cent OS 5 to rssh: "Shell not changed"

Tags: centos, shell

I installed rssh on CentOS 5 from RPMForge. Then I tried to change the shell to rssh to one existing user like this:

```
[root@ddinvps ofertoza]# chsh -s /usr/bin/rssh ofertoza
Changing shell for ofertoza.
Warning: "/usr/bin/rssh" is not listed in /etc/shells
Shell not changed.
```

OK, I added /usr/bin/rssh to /etc/shells and now I don't get the warning, just this:

```
[root@ddinvps ofertoza]# chsh -s /usr/bin/rssh ofertoza
Changing shell for ofertoza.
Shell not changed.
```

Any ideas why would this happen? It's a normal user with /home/ofertoza as home dir. I want to use rssh to restrict the access for sftp/scp to only that dir where will reside the files of one website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just edit and change the /bin/bash into /usr/bin/rssh directly on /etc/passwd

Answer (score 1):

The man page for `usermod` gives the following option:

```
-s, --shell SHELL
        The name of the user's new login shell. Setting this field to blank
        causes the system to select the default login shell.
```